# java StringBuffer send email some part html some part java format updated

Tags: java, html

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
try{
    msg.setSubject("Test Notification");
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(sentTo, false));
    StringBuffer updated= new StringBuffer(
    String str1 = String.format("%d", 101)        +  
 String str2 = String.format("%s", "Amar Singh") +
    String str3 = String.format("%f", 101.00)+       
    String str4 = String.format("%x", 101)+     
    String str5 = String.format("%c", 'c')+

"<p style=\"color:red;\">BRIDGEYE</p>");

    
       
    
    String regular_message = Str1+str2+str3+str4+str5;
    
    //msg.setText(reguar_mesage);
    msg.setContent(updated, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());
    Transport.send(msg);

}catch(MessagingException me){
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "sendEmailNotification: {0}", me.getMessage());
}
```

Hi All,

So I'm trying to send an email that is half java part half html content. My html part is no longer in this code. I just didn't want to copy and paste it cause it gets long and really complex lol.

So I tried set text for the regular part then set content for the html part but the  set content override the set text. So the set text is not showing up on email. I then try combining both strings in set content. But the regular java part gets converted to html.

How would I do half java format. half html?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE I change it to a string buffer

as you can see some parts of my string buffer has html some has java format
when I send the email it just gets convert to html. How do I keep the html html,
and java java format. Much thanks appreciated

Comment: update I might make my email body a string buffer. Is it possible to have the string buffer as some part html format? Some parts not?

Comment: Why not embed the regular message in a separate div?

Comment: @MubarakaBharucha check update